# Feasibility of solving this problem with venn diagrams or 2x2 tables

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Of the people in a certain survey, 58 percent were at most 40 years
>   old and 70 percent were at most 60 years old. If 252 of the people in
>   the survey were more than 40 years old and at most 60 years old, what
>   was the total number of people in the survey?

Is it possible to solve this problem using venn diagrams or 2x2 tables?

That's not how the solutions manual did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can represent the above situation in a Venn diagram. It can be achieved by drawing two concentric circles.

- The inner circle represents people with $\le 40$ years old and $58\%$ of the total.
- The outer circle represents peolpe with $\le 60$ years old. It has $70\%$ of the total; since $58\%$ is already accounted by the inner circle, the anullus that represents people with $40 < \text{age} \le 60$ is $12\%$ of the total.

The statement says that these $12\%$ is 252 people, and thus you can find from here the total amount of people in the survey.